# How can i show a piece code in my application

Tags: android

I developing a simple tutorial application. in that I want to add some code, so how can I show in the application. I tried showing with using text view.
Here :

```
 <string name="code"> Resources res = getResources();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                res.openRawResource(R.raw.get_accounts)));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line)
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }</string>

TextView txtCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_message);
        txtCode.setText(R.string.code);
```

but it's not a formatted way of coding, so please suggest me is there any special methods for showing code views in android.

Comment: my code is not a html code.

Comment: Mark up your code as you would to display it in HTML (using `<tt>`, `<br>`, etc. tags) and then use the technique shown in the duplicate question.